# Action when tableview row selection has changed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview implemented. The list shows fine, but I want to detect when the row selection has been changed. I am trying to do a certain action when the row selection is changed, for example, print("row selection has changed ")

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tableArray.count
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "exploreCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can observer selection state from this 2 delegate methods. So when you select any cell it will call `didSelectRowAt` delegate method and if you tap on selected cell again it will call `didDeselectRowAt`

Make sure to set tableView selection property to multiple selection incase if you want user to select multiple cell

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
```

Swift Delegate methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Your code here
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I implemented the same code, but first it didn't work because of tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) in the didSelectRowAt method 
 which I had to remove in order for it to work as intended.

Comment: Can you please update code so i will take a look. Don't need to remove didSelectRow

Comment: override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedExploreCell = indexPath.row
        self.announceAfterClick(selectedRow: selectedExploreCell)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }